# How do I get a production version of the Chromecast Sender SDK to include in my application

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

The Chromecast SDK download page has the following disclaimer:
"Warning: The current Google Cast SDK is a preview SDK intended for development and testing purposes only, not for production apps..."

What is the procedure for getting a version of the Chromecast Sender SDK from Google that I can include in my production app?

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible for high profile apps at this point, like Netflix, HBO Go, Youtube, etc.

In early December, Google is hosting a developer event in anticipation for the upcoming release of the Google Cast SDK.

Once the SDK exists preview, I am sure the Chromecast team will make an announcement.

**EDIT: [Chromecast is now open to developers](http://chrome.blogspot.com/2014/02/chromecast-is-now-open-to-developers.html)**